# Is it possible to translate Kotlin to Java without Kotlin libraries?

Tags: java, kotlin

Is it possible to translate Kotlin to Java without Kotlin libraries?
Some environments can only run standard Java files (some acm online judgments for example). Is it possible using Kotlin in this kind case?

I tried using decompile Kotlin byte code, but most cases it imports Kotlin's libraries (`import kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt;` for example). Can it be translated to pure Java?

Comment: isn't kotlin bytecode the same as JVM bytecode?

Comment: No, since Kotlin depends on the Kotlin stdlib (which includes some nice extra utility functions and classes not found in Java). The compiled classes themselves should work, given that the stdlib is on the classpath (i.e. embedded in a .jar for example), but in the environment you suggest, probably not.

Comment: If you can compile Kotlin, then you should be able to run it as well. Can you elaborate on what environment this might not hold?

Comment: If Leetcode doesn't support Kotlin, I can only submit Java code in this case. How to use Kotlin in this case?